# difference between static and production environments in docpad

Tags: docpad

"production" environment is specified in "[to a node.js hosting provider](http://docpad.org/docs/deploy#to-a-node-js-hosting-provider)" section of docpad's deploy guide while "static" is specified in ["to static servers"](http://docpad.org/docs/deploy#to-static-servers-apache-nginx-etc) section.

What is the real difference between both? And is is safe to use custom environment name?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few parts to this.

The environment is specified by the `--env` CLI flag:

- `docpad <action>` will run in the `development` environment
- `docpad <action> --env static` will run in the `static` environment
- `docpad <action> --env production` will run in the `production` environment

Now the default configuration is actually assumed to be the configuration for your production environment, with the `development`, `static`, and whatever other environment actually extending your default (production) configuration via the `environments` configuration property. You can see the special environment configuration the DocPad core specifies [here](https://github.com/bevry/docpad/blob/1492e864b179d40af5ef0bd5a4b83a7928039e44/src/lib/docpad.coffee#L962-L972).

Plugins will also specify custom environment configuration as well. So for instance the [clean urls plugin](http://docpad.org/p/cleanurls) will by default just rely on the DocPad node.js server to do the clean urls, but if we are running in a static environment, then it will write special static redirect files instead. [Here is the code for how it does it.](https://github.com/docpad/docpad-plugin-cleanurls/blob/0cc0450ef04d3abb4b19d2e12e1971016c8099dd/src/cleanurls.plugin.coffee#L81)